# ios swift - AVPlayerViewController video not fit into the view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Before starting to the point, just want to to tell, now i jump to iPhone Development, I am new to this.

I have the problem in the view of the video. I need to render view in the view. I have done something like this

```
     override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    moviePlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
    if let player = moviePlayer {
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: "http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/p/1/sp/11000/playManifest/entryId/0_eruqsdasd/flavorIds/1111/format/applehttp/protocol/http/a.m3u8")! )
        playerVideo = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.player = playerVideo
        player.view.frame = self.videoView.frame
        player.view.sizeToFit()
        player.showsPlaybackControls = true
        videoView.addSubview(player.view)

        print("SeekTime:Table: \(moviePlayer.player?.currentTime())")
    }

}
```

The output is something like this.

[image]

Could you please help me out this
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf5VY.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try present VC instead of add as subview

```
self.presentViewController(moviePlayer, animated: true) {
    self.moviePlayer.player!.play()
}
```

Otherwise, you might go check the frame of your `videoView`

Answer (score 1):

Your video-player has an Y offset, which needs to be reduced so that it fits on the screen, try either -

```
//get size of screen
var screenSize : CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;

//set width and height of screen into screenHeight and screenWidth
var screenHeight = screenSize.height;
var screenWidth = screenSize.width;

//re-position video-frame
player.view.frame.position.y = screenHeight * 0;
```

if the `player.view.frame` method doesn't work try the following instead:

```
player.view.frame.center.y = screenHeight * 0;
```

if the `player.view` has no member called `frame` use `player.frame` instead.